# 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer - Is there a way to convert a list to integers?

Tags: python, list

I am new to the Python language. In one subject, they ask us to do the homework with this language and to investigate it on our own. In this part of the code, I first declare the range with the `range(0, 1024)` method, and the random numbers are generated with the `sample` method, and I believe that these are saved in a list, so what I want to do next is that these Numbers that were generated randomly convert them to binary, but I get this error:

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

So I don't know if there is a way to convert a list to whole numbers or I don't know what else they would recommend me to do ...

This is my code:

```
y = list(range(0, 1024))
numRandom = sample(y, 10)
print(numRandom)
print(bin(numRandom))
```

Comment: You need to apply the `bin()` function to each element of the list, not the list itself.

Comment: You probably want a list comprehension around multiple `bin` calls. Also, there's no need to convert `y` to a list; in fact, it makes things worse.

Comment: oh I see, I will check that, thanks

Comment: use `list(map(lambda x: bin(x), numRandom))` instead of `bin(numRandom)`

Comment: @o11c, there is a need to convert `y` to a list because `range` in python 3 produces a sequence, and `random.sample` requires a list

Comment: @smac89 `random.sample` explicitly requires either a `collections.abc.Set` (which gets converted to `tuple` unconditionally) or a `collections.abc.Sequence` (which only gets converted to `list` in one branch). The latter handles `range` just fine. Tested with Python 3.7, which is plenty old by now.

Comment: @o11c you are right that it does in fact work with sequences, but since python 3.10, it no longer works with set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list with the binary representations of each number in the original list.

```
print([bin(x) for x in numRandom])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `numRandom` is a list, not an integer.  Specifically, it's a list of ten random `int`s.

To apply the `bin` function to the first element of the list, you could do:

```
print(bin(numRandom[0]))
```

You could iterate over the list and do this to each one with a `for` loop:

```
for num in numRandom:
    print(bin(num))
```

Or you could build a list of binary representations with a list comprehension:

```
print([bin(num) for num in numRandom])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Map

```
print([*map(bin, random.sample(y, 10))])
```

#### Or Using List Comprehension

```
print([bin(x) for x in random.sample(y, 10)])
```